# How to create a new struct when an error occurs

Tags: ruby, struct

I am trying to make a text based game using ruby to learn the language, I want to throw an error if a player enters a string incorrectly, it should ask them to start the character making process over again.

My issue is that when I re-call the function to make the character, it creates a new struct and keeps the old one. So at the end I have something that is printing the new corrected struct as well as the old wrong struct. I obviously only want to keep the correct one so how do I go about getting rid of the old one?

```
 Character = Struct.new(:name,:race,:alignment,:str,:dex,:int,:const,:char,:wis)
def makeChar()
    newChar = Character.new()
    until i == 6 do
        case skillArray[i]
        when "str"
            newChar.str = rolledStats[i]
        when "int"
            newChar.int = rolledStats[i]
        when "dex"
            newChar.dex = rolledStats[i]
        when "wis"
            newChar.wis = rolledStats[i]
        when "const"
            newChar.const = rolledStats[i]
        when "char"
            newChar.char = rolledStats[i]
        else
            puts("It appears you have entered an invalid value for a skill")
            puts("Please try again but enter only the following: str, dex, int, char, wis, const")
            makeChar()
        end
        i += 1
    end
    puts("Our brave adventurer's name is #{name} the #{race}")
        puts("#{name}'s stats are as follows:\n Str: #{newChar.str} \n Dex: #{newChar.dex}
            Const: #{newChar.const} \n Int: #{newChar.int} \n Wis: #{newChar.wis} \n Char: #{newChar.char}")
        print("#{name} prepare for your quest!")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you edit your question to include your faulty code?

Comment: I have added the code :)

Answer (score 0):

There are cases when you need to 'get rid of' variables but this doesn't sound like one.

Just see this example:

```
word = "test"
def guess_word
  guess = gets.chomp
  exit if word == guess
end
loop do
  puts "guess word"
  guess_word
end
```

This program runs on a loop. Each iteration, it prompts the user for a word. If the word is correct, it exits. You can see in `guess_word` that the `guess` variable is assigned each time the method is called.

If you have a method which defines a variable, that variable's scope is *just in that method* **unless** there is a variable with the same name in a higher scope.